# Как выводить информацию с http-запроса в приложении Android на Java

Tags: java, android

Я делаю http-запрос и в ответ он возвращает **JSON** со списком товаров. Каким образом мне этот список выводить в нужном мне месте в приложении Android? С JSON работать могу, только не понимаю как правильно выводить полученную информацию. Насколько я понимаю, нужно мучаться с этими `LayerLayout` и так далее, потому что читал, что выводить с помощью HTML неправильно.

Я ещё новичок в этом, поэтому просьба не ругаться. Гуглил, но ничего толкового по этой теме не нашёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаешь запрос в сеть, к примеру с помощью `Retrofit`.
Оттуда приходит ответ `JSON`.
Дубасишь этот `json` через `PojoGenerator` и составляешь модель данных на его основе. Далее берешь ее и пропихиваешь в `RecyclerView.Adapter` через параметры `ArrayList`. И все. В адаптере выводишь нужные поля на экран. 
Итого в сухом остатке вбиваете в ютуб:
`RecyclerView`.
`Retrofit`.
`Pojo`, `Json to Pojo`. Очень много готовых примеров в сети на данную тему. Можно даде код скопировать только поменять адрес доставки)

Answer (score 2):

Всё верно. Json тебе только данные даст. Примитивы. Тебе нужно сделать полноценный UI. Layout на котором будет всё держаться, в который ты поместишь товары. И после получения ответа, я так понимаю, для каждого товара создавать плашку с информацией и помещать их на этот Layout.

Например как на картинке (рандомной с инета) помещены списком диалоги:

[image: Пример]